# xamarin forms clear session ios xamarin forms

Tags: c#, ios, cookies, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

im trying to clear the cookies with this code, i dont understand why its not working.

I already have tried with this:

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
```

i think i have to include

```
using Foundation;
```

but it displays an error if i put it in the directives section. i need to know how to execute this code only on ios, right now im running it apparently with no problem but it doesnt clear the cookies. i dont know how to point especifically to this file to be executed.

here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using app_app.Helpers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using static app_app.MainPage;
#if __IOS__
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
#endif


namespace app_app
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ActualizarDatos : ContentPage
    {

        private MainPage.loginInfo userInfo;


        public ActualizarDatos(loginInfo userInfo)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.userInfo = userInfo;
            nombre.Text = userInfo.nombre;
            apellido.Text = userInfo.apellido;
            email.Text = userInfo.email;
            cedula.Text = userInfo.cedula;

            nombreHeader.Text = userInfo.nombre + " " + userInfo.apellido;




        }



        private async void btnCambiar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new CambiarContrasena(userInfo) { Title = "app Cambiar Contraseña" });
        }


        public void DeleteAllCookiesForSite()
        {
        #if __IOS__

            NSHttpCookieStorage storage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;

            foreach (NSHttpCookie cookie in storage.Cookies)
            {
                if (cookie.Domain == ".facebook.com")
                {
                    storage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
                }

            }

            NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
            #endif

        }



        private async void btnCerrar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            userInfo = null;
            DeleteAllCookiesForSite();
            Settings.IsLoggedIn = false;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());

        }


        private async void Actualizar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nombre.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe ingresar un nombre válido", "Aceptar");
                nombre.Focus();
                return;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apellido.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe ingresar un apellido válido", "Aceptar");
                apellido.Focus();
                return;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cedula.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe ingresar una cédula válida", "Aceptar");
                cedula.Focus();
                return;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.Text))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe ingresar un email", "Aceptar");
                email.Focus();
                return;
            }

            if (proyecto.SelectedIndex == -1) {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe indicar la linea de negocios de su preferencia", "Aceptar");
                return; 
            }

            /*if (adquirio_proyecto.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe indicar si ha adquirido proyectos", "Aceptar");
                return;
            }*/

            if (recibir_notificaciones.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe indicar si desea recibir notificaciones", "Aceptar");
                return;
            }



            btnActualizaUsuario.IsEnabled = false;



            try
            {

                var uri = new Uri("https://www.app.com.co/app/service.php");

                //await DisplayAlert("debug", userInfo.id, "Aceptar");

                var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]{
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", userInfo.id),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("nombre", nombre.Text),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("apellido", apellido.Text),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("cedula", cedula.Text),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email.Text),
                    //new KeyValuePair<string, string>("adquirio_proyecto", adquirio_proyecto.Items[adquirio_proyecto.SelectedIndex]),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("proyecto", proyecto.Items[proyecto.SelectedIndex]),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("recibir_notificaciones", recibir_notificaciones.Items[recibir_notificaciones.SelectedIndex]),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("task", "actualizaUsuario")
                });



                var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();

                myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
                myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
                myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");

                var response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(uri.ToString(), formContent);

                var stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        //await DisplayAlert("debug", stringContent, "Aceptar");
                        switch (stringContent)
                        {
                            case "success":
                                stringContent = "";
                                var BienV = "Sus datos han sido actualizados debes iniciar sesión para ver los cambios";
                                await DisplayAlert("Registro Éxitoso", BienV, "Aceptar");
                                userInfo = null;
                                await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
                        break;
                            case "failed":
                                var VuelveA = "Algo salio mal, intente mas tarde";
                                await DisplayAlert("Registro no exitoso Incorrecto", VuelveA, "Aceptar");
                                email.Text = string.Empty;
                                btnActualizaUsuario.IsEnabled = true;
                                stringContent = "";
                                break;
                            case "exist":
                                var Existe = "Su correo se encuentra registrado";
                                await DisplayAlert("Registro no exitoso Incorrecto", Existe, "Aceptar");
                                email.Text = string.Empty;
                                btnActualizaUsuario.IsEnabled = true;
                                stringContent = "";
                                break;
                        }


            }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        var Msj = ex.Message;
                        await DisplayAlert("Error", Msj, "Aceptar");
                        return;

                    }
        }

    }}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used dependency injection, so in my Portable Project I call

```
          //required for iOS
        DependencyService.Get<IPlatform>().DeleteAllCookies();
```

Where iPlatform is

```
public interface IPlatform
{
    void DeleteAllCookies();
}
```

Then in platform.cs in the iOS project I have

```
internal class Platform : IPlatform
{
    public void DeleteAllCookies()
    {
        foreach (var c in NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.Cookies)
        {
            NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.DeleteCookie(c);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the Android project the function is empty:

```
    public void DeleteAllCookies()
    {
    }
```